# Citation of an article is not reflected in Google Scholar database

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Some of my published articles have been cited by an article published in March 2017. But surprisingly citation to my articles is are not being shown in Google Scholar. What could be the reason? Where should I place my query for citation update?

Comment: Have they been cited by a journal indexed by google scholar?

Comment: Was the article really published in March, or was it just a preprint? Note that some journals also have a "online first" publication, before publishing the journal in print a few months later.

Comment: @AnderBiguri is implicitly hinting that Google Scholar will not find the citation if it isn't an indexed source. I'll add: indexing takes time.

Comment: The journals are SCI indexed and the article is fully published in March 2017.

Comment: The actual question here is why would you bother about this citation at all, and not why it did not appear in automatically generated database.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to "indexing takes time (*if* it is done)" and taking into account that your journals in view are SCI indexed, consider Clarivate Analytics' / Thomson Reuters' *Web of Science* as a subscription based *alternative* bibliographic database. It has historical roots to the SCI ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_Science)).

Perhaps field dependent, but from own recent experience in chemistry, between appearance on the publisher's site (Wiley) of an about 1 year-old journal and *Web of Science* the gap was just about half a year.  To accelerate visibility of your work during this period, you may import publications as yours *via* the doi in the [ORCID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORCID) database, and simply link to the your personalized profile page there.

It is equally possible that your publication's abstract appeared on other sites than the one of the publisher's and consequently was cited.  [Scopus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scopus) (more oriented towards engineering than sciences, backed by Elsevier) is a potential source.  [ResearchGate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ResearchGate) and the listings of [Mendeley'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendeley) catalogue add to it, too.